# Spring batch Cassandra to Apache Solr

Tags: solr, cassandra, spring-batch

we have a task of moving huge amount of data from Cassandra to Apache Solr. I'm planning to use Spring batch for the migration. I wanted to know if someone had solved similar problem. I also wanted to know what was the partitioning technique used to grab data from Cassandra.
I'm using datastax driver to interact with Cassandra.
Thanks!

Comment: plain Cassandra or DSE??

Comment: Plain cassandra